# login_user() Nonetype object has no attribute is_active with flask_login

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI), when I tried to remember the user logged in after signing up, it doesn't work and shows `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_active'` error, although, it did registered the user, so I don't know what's happening, it was working before so I know the problem is not in the function itself.

Here's the code:

```
def signup():
    if request.method == "POST":
        # getting information into backend
        email = request.form.get('email')
        user_name = request.form.get('userName')
        password_first = request.form.get('passwordFirst')
        password_confirm = request.form.get('passwordConfirm')

        # Checking if everything's ok

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()

        if user:
            flash("This email is already linked to an account", category="error")
        elif len(email) < 3:
            flash("Email must be at least 3 characters", category="error")
        elif len(user_name) < 2:
            flash("Username must be at least 2 characters", category="error")
        elif password_first != password_confirm:
            flash("Passwords don't match", category="error")
        elif len(password_first) < 8:
            flash("Password must be at least 8 characters long", category="error")

        # adding user to database
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, user_name=user_name, password=generate_password_hash(password_first, method="sha256"))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(user, remember=True)
            flash("Account created successfully! :)", category="success")
            return redirect(url_for("views.home"))


    return render_template("signup.html")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should `login_user(user, remember=True)`, instead be `login_user(new_user, remember=True)`?